# Alert not showing up in my html code

Tags: javascript, html

I have all of my validation code figured 
out but I'm not quite sure on how to code an
alert to pop up before the form is submitted 
but after the validation is complete. Pretty
much my alerts which fields have errors, and 
what the errors are aren't showing up when 
I submit this form. All it is direct me to the 
submit successful page despite errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<script>
function validateForm() {
var fName = document.forms["orderForm"].firstName.value;//first name validation
        if(fName==null || fName=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('firstNameError').innerHTML= "Please enter a first name.";
            return false;
        }


        var lName = document.forms["orderForm"].lastName.value;//last name validation
        if(lName==null || lName=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('lastNameError').innerHTML= "Please enter a last name.";
            return false;
        }


        var address = document.forms["orderForm"].address.value;//address validation
        if(address==null || address=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('addressError').innerHTML= "Please enter an address.";
            return false;
        }


        var city = document.forms["orderForm"].city.value;//city validation
        if(city==null || city=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('cityError').innerHTML= "Please enter a city.";
            return false;
        }


        var pCodeCheck = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;//postal code validation
        if(postalCode.value.match(pCodeCheck))
        {
            //do nothing
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('postalCoderror').innerHTML= "Please enter a valid postal code.";
            return false;
        }

                    // makes sure you cannot order a negative number of items


        var itemQTY = document.forms["orderForm"].widget1qty.value;
        if(itemQTY < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError').innerHTML= "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            return false;
        }


        var itemQTY2 = document.forms["orderForm"].widget2qty.value;
        if(itemQTY2 < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError2').innerHTML= "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            return false;
        }


        var itemQTY3 = document.forms["orderForm"].widget3qty.value;
        if(itemQTY3 < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError3').innerHTML= "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            return false;
        }

                    //makes sure there is at least one item ordered
        var wid1Qty = document.getElementById('widget1qty').value;
        var wid2Qty = document.getElementById('widget2qty').value;
        var wid3Qty = document.getElementById('widget3qty').value;
        if(wid1Qty + wid2Qty + wid3Qty == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('itemQTY').innerHTML= "You must order atleast one item.";
            return false;
        }
        var total1;
        var total2;
        var total3;
        var total4;

        total1 = document.forms['orderForm']['widget1qty'].value * 5;
        total2 = document.forms['orderForm']['widget2qty'].value * 15;
        total3 = document.forms['orderForm']['widget3qty'].value * 25;
        total4 = (total1 + total2 + total3)
        alert('Your total is: $' + total4 + '.00');
        return;
    }

function startValidate(){
        validateForm();
        document.forms['orderForm'].submit();

}
</script>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <h2 class="center">Order Form</h2> <!-- action="processForm.html"       "javascript:void(0)" -->
    <form name="orderForm" method="post" onsubmit="validate();" action="processForm.html">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
    <table>

        <tr>
            <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" size="30"></td>
            <td id="firstNameError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>Last Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" size="30"></td>
            <td id="lastNameError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>Address:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30"></td>
            <td id="addressError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>City:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="30"></td>
            <td id="cityError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>Province:</td>
            <td><select name="province" id="province" size="1">
                    <option disabled>Select a province</option>
                    <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                    <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                    <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
                    <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                    <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                    <option value="QC">Québec</option>
                    <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
                    <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
                    <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
                    <option value="NF">Newfoundland</option>
                    <option value="YK">Yukon</option>
                    <option value="NWT">Northwest Territories</option>
                    <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>Postal Code:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="postalCode" id="postalCode" maxlength="6"></td>
            <td id="postalCoderror"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Order Information</legend>

        <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Select your products:<br>
            <td>Widget #1&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="widget1qty" id="widget1qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$5.00/ea</strong></td>
                <td id="qtyError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Widget #2&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="widget2qty" id="widget2qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$15.00/ea</strong></td>
                <td id="qtyError2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Widget #3&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="widget3qty" id="widget3qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$25.00/ea</strong></td>
                <td id="qtyError3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="itemQTY"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Shipping Type:</td>
            <td>Standard ($5.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeStandard" value="Standard" checked></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Express ($10.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeExpress" value="Express"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Overnight ($20.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeOvernight" value="Overnight"></td>
        </tr>

        </table>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Submit Order</legend>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" onsubmit="startValidate()" value="Submit Order">
            <td><input type="reset" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" value="Reset Form"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>  
</body>
```

Comment: `onsubmit="validate();"` - unknown function `validate`

Comment: write javascript code at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Please post code no more than 10% of what you posted so we can easily see what is actually going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h2 class="center">Order Form</h2> <!-- action="processForm.html"       "javascript:void(0)" -->
        <form name="orderForm" method="post" action="processForm.html" onsubmit="return startValidate()">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Personal Information</legend>
                <table>

                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="required">*</span>First Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" size="30"></td>
                        <td id="firstNameError"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="required">*</span>Last Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" size="30"></td>
                        <td id="lastNameError"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="required">*</span>Address:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30"></td>
                        <td id="addressError"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="required">*</span>City:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="30"></td>
                        <td id="cityError"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="required">*</span>Province:</td>
                        <td><select name="province" id="province" size="1">
                                <option disabled>Select a province</option>
                                <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                                <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                                <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
                                <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                                <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                                <option value="QC">Québec</option>
                                <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
                                <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
                                <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
                                <option value="NF">Newfoundland</option>
                                <option value="YK">Yukon</option>
                                <option value="NWT">Northwest Territories</option>
                                <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="required">*</span>Postal Code:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="postalCode" id="postalCode" maxlength="6"></td>
                        <td id="postalCoderror"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Order Information</legend>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="3">Select your products:<br>
                        <td>Widget #1&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" name="widget1qty" id="widget1qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$5.00/ea</strong></td>
                        <td id="qtyError"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Widget #2&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" name="widget2qty" id="widget2qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$15.00/ea</strong></td>
                        <td id="qtyError2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Widget #3&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" name="widget3qty" id="widget3qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$25.00/ea</strong></td>
                        <td id="qtyError3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="3"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td id="itemQTY"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="3">Shipping Type:</td>
                        <td>Standard ($5.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeStandard" value="Standard" checked></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Express ($10.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeExpress" value="Express"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Overnight ($20.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeOvernight" value="Overnight"></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Submit Order</legend>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit Order">
                    <td><input type="reset" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" value="Reset Form"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>  
</body>
```

JS:

```
  <script>
    function validateForm() {
        var errors = 0;
        var fName = document.forms["orderForm"].firstName.value;//first name validation
        if (fName == null || fName == "")
        {
            document.getElementById('firstNameError').innerHTML = "Please enter a first name.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('firstNameError').innerHTML = "";
        }


        var lName = document.forms["orderForm"].lastName.value;//last name validation
        if (lName == null || lName == "")
        {
            document.getElementById('lastNameError').innerHTML = "Please enter a last name.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('lastNameError').innerHTML = "";
        }


        var address = document.forms["orderForm"].address.value;//address validation
        if (address == null || address == "")
        {
            document.getElementById('addressError').innerHTML = "Please enter an address.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('addressError').innerHTML = "";
        }


        var city = document.forms["orderForm"].city.value;//city validation
        if (city == null || city == "")
        {
            document.getElementById('cityError').innerHTML = "Please enter a city.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('cityError').innerHTML = "";
        }


        var pCodeCheck = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;//postal code validation
        if (postalCode.value.match(pCodeCheck))
        {
            document.getElementById('postalCoderror').innerHTML = "";
        }
        else
        {

            document.getElementById('postalCoderror').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid postal code.";
            errors++;
        }

        // makes sure you cannot order a negative number of items


        var itemQTY = document.forms["orderForm"].widget1qty.value;
        if (itemQTY < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError').innerHTML = "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('qtyError').innerHTML = "";
        }


        var itemQTY2 = document.forms["orderForm"].widget2qty.value;
        if (itemQTY2 < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError2').innerHTML = "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('qtyError2').innerHTML = "";
        }


        var itemQTY3 = document.forms["orderForm"].widget3qty.value;
        if (itemQTY3 < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError3').innerHTML = "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('qtyError3').innerHTML = "";
        }

        //makes sure there is at least one item ordered
        var wid1Qty = document.getElementById('widget1qty').value;
        var wid2Qty = document.getElementById('widget2qty').value;
        var wid3Qty = document.getElementById('widget3qty').value;
        if (wid1Qty + wid2Qty + wid3Qty == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('itemQTY').innerHTML = "You must order atleast one item.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('itemQTY').innerHTML = "";
        }
        var total1;
        var total2;
        var total3;
        var total4;

        total1 = document.forms['orderForm']['widget1qty'].value * 5;
        total2 = document.forms['orderForm']['widget2qty'].value * 15;
        total3 = document.forms['orderForm']['widget3qty'].value * 25;
        total4 = (total1 + total2 + total3);
        alert('Your total is: $' + total4 + '.00');
        return errors;
    }

    function startValidate() {
        var errors = validateForm();
        if (errors == 0) {
            document.forms['orderForm'].submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this but it submits and gives me a value regardless of whether the personal info is correct

Comment: Ok I made some edits. this should work for you. Let me know what are your exact result expectations.

Comment: No problem. Anytime. :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to have

```
<form name="orderForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

than

```
<form name="orderForm" method="post" onsubmit="validate();">
```

The "return" part of it makes sure javascript returns the true/false value and does whatever necessary action is needed

and also in your script try having a one boolean variable that acts as a control so that for example "valid" if 9/10 are correct, the boolean value valid will be false and then the form will not submit.
Example below

```
function validateForm() {
  var valid = new Boolean(true);
  //code here - example
  var fName = document.forms["orderForm"].firstName.value;//first name validation
    if(fName==null || fName=="")
    {
        valid = false;
        document.getElementById('firstNameError').innerHTML= "Please enter a first name.";
        return false;
    }
  return valid

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `startValidate()` it will kick off the `document.forms.submit` line whether or not the `validateForm()` returns `true` or `false`. You need to only submit the form if `validateForm()` returns `true`. A `false` return in your validator won't kill the `startValidate()` function like you are thinking it will.

Try moving the `document.forms['orderForm'].submit();` up into the bottom of your `validateForm()` method after you've checked all the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `onsubmit="startValidate();"`

```
 <form name="orderForm" method="post" onsubmit="startValidate();"   action="processForm.html">
```

You can simply use the jQuery Validate plugin as follows.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no use of `startValidate` function. Just remove that.
2. your form tag should be `<form name="orderForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="processForm.html">`
3. Use this as submit button, `<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit Order">` //<- removed onsubmit="startValidate()" as this is not required.

**Most important, just validate your HTML before posting here.**

Comment: Tried it, nothing happened